# How to make a background like the one in the picture using polygon

Tags: html, css, background, polygon

I'm wondering how to make such a header using the clip path polygon command. It would be simpler to insert an image but I'd like to learn and use animation for this in CSS which I can do.

When I tried different methods the divs were far apart and there were various problems with it. I would appreciate your advice.

This is my code and current progress:

[image: Example Image]

```css
body {
  font-family: "Anonymous Pro", monospace;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1, 7;
  color: #777;
  padding: 30px;
}

.header {
  height: 80vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 18.7% 37.8%,
    rgb(238, 226, 226) 0%,
    rgb(211, 219, 223) 90%
  );

  clip-path: polygon(100% 11%, 100% 77%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: movefromright;
  animation-duration: 1.7s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.image {
  background-image: url(img/logo2.png);
  height: 80vh;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  animation-name: movefromleft;
  animation-duration: 1.7s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="image"></div>
      <div class="text-box">
        <div class="header-button">
          <a href="#zawartosc" class="btn btn-blue">Przejdź dalej</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

I would like to get this effect:

[image]

Source: Canva

Comment: You want the red and the blue? I'm not sure what you're actually asking for here. You polygon works for the gray background.

Comment: Are you certain you want to use clippath or would linear gradients be more suitable? I ask because it depends on what effect you want on different viewport aspect ratios.

Comment: I would like to get the blue color as well as this red one

Comment: you may use a linear-gradient then clip a child with the radial gradient and probably use less or different markup: https://jsfiddle.net/mha7w59t/

Comment: @AHaworth I'm honestly not sure. Just want to get the effect like the final photo. In the first photo I have the polygon itself with a gray gradient. He wants a way to add red from the top and blue from the bottom to make a final background like in the last photo.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus HM i can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are are a few ways that I'd work on handling this. First `clip-path` doesn't really allow you to do things "outside" of it. So you won't be able to get both the clipped background and the red and blue. I made two snippets for you to check out.

This first snippet keeps the markup as it is, and uses `::before` and `::after` elements to make the background. The `::before` creates the red and blue, and the `::after` has the clipped background that includes the radial gradient.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Anonymous Pro", monospace;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1, 7;
  color: #777;
  padding: 30px;
}

.header {
  height: 80vh;
  position: relative;
}

.header::before {  
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 15, 240, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 15, 240, 1) 100%);
  bottom: 0;
  color: black;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}

.header::after {
  animation-name: movefromright;
  animation-duration: 1.7s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  background-image: radial-gradient( circle at 18.7% 37.8%, rgb(238, 226, 226) 0%, rgb(211, 219, 223) 90%);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 11%, 100% 77%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.image {
  background-image: url(img/logo2.png);
  height: 80vh;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  animation-name: movefromleft;
  animation-duration: 1.7s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="text-box">
    <div class="header-button">
      <a href="#zawartosc" class="btn btn-blue">Przejdź dalej</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

This second snippet changes the markup, which I would recommend. This would allow you to have everything inside the clipped container and have the blue and red background. This would also allow you to not have to mess with z-index and pseudo-elements. Neither of those are bad, but I think it would be easier to just wrap the header and apply a background there.

The content of the clipped element will sill need to fit inside the clipped container. There are a few ways that you can handle that. If you make the clipped container a sibling element and set it to `position: absolute;` it will sit behind everything. To do this, you'd need to make the header element (that has the red and blue background) have `position: relative;`.

I'd also note that your `.image` div takes up the full height, that is what you aren't seeing the contents when it's inside the clipped container.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Anonymous Pro", monospace;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1, 7;
  color: #777;
  padding: 30px;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 15, 240, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 15, 240, 1) 100%);
}

.header-wrapper {
  height: 80vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient( circle at 18.7% 37.8%, rgb(238, 226, 226) 0%, rgb(211, 219, 223) 90%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 11%, 100% 77%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-position: top;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: movefromright;
  animation-duration: 1.7s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.image {
  background-image: url(img/logo2.png);
  height: 80vh;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  animation-name: movefromleft;
  animation-duration: 1.7s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text-box">
      <div class="header-button">
        <a href="#zawartosc" class="btn btn-blue">Przejdź dalej</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Without seeing the full design and knowing how it works, I'm not sure I can give you a better answer, but this should give you what you need.